# Android Automatic Refresh Button

Tags: android, button, refresh

I'm having trouble with something that seems like it should be very simple.  I have a frame layout with 2 Buttons (one on top of the other naturally).  When I click on the top button, it automatically takes me to a website, and the button beneath it replaces it to be the visible one.  I want to set up an automatic refresh so that a few seconds later, the button that was originally on top becomes on top again. Thank you for any help you can give! Here is the Java, and with my attempt at creating an automatic refresh:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ImageButton bJava1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final ImageButton bJava2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final WebView webview1= (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    final MediaPlayer sound= MediaPlayer.create(Youtube.this, R.raw.soundclip1);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Refresh = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

        bJava1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                webview1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
                if(sound.isPlaying()){
                    bJava1.setVisibility(ImageButton.VISIBLE);
                    bJava2.setVisibility(ImageButton.GONE);
                }else {
                    sound.start();
                    bJava1.setVisibility(ImageButton.GONE);
                    bJava2.setVisibility(ImageButton.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

        });
        handler.postDelayed(Refresh, 10000);
    }
};
handler.post(Refresh);
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, that your Refresh runnable only registers a onClickListener on the first button and calls itself every 10 seconds, you should register the onClickListener only once outside the Runnable and only call the if block within your Refresh.run() Method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

final ImageButton bJava1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button1);
final ImageButton bJava2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button2);
final WebView webview1= (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
final MediaPlayer sound= MediaPlayer.create(Youtube.this, R.raw.soundclip1);
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Refresh = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       if(sound.isPlaying()){
                bJava1.setVisibility(ImageButton.VISIBLE);
                bJava2.setVisibility(ImageButton.GONE);
            }else {
                sound.start();
                bJava1.setVisibility(ImageButton.GONE);
                bJava2.setVisibility(ImageButton.VISIBLE);
            }
     }
};
bJava1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            webview1.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            handler.postDelayed(Refresh, 10000);
        }

    });
```